# XMLStarlet: How to select XML, returning empty

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a pretty easy problem to solve, but have been at it for days without luck.

I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<readiness>
    <model>
        <name>Power</name>
        <state>
            <pdlReq>PASS</pdlReq>
            <fileReq>PASS</fileReq>
        </state>
    </model>
</readiness>
```

And I am trying to select.. anything really. I can't get even the simpliest examples to work. What I've tried:

- `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//readiness"  modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/readiness"  modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "readiness"  modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/readiness/model[name='Power']" -v pdl modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/readiness/model[name='Power']" -v pdl -n  modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/readiness/model[name='Power']" modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//readiness"  modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/readiness"  modelReadinessState.xml`
- `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "readiness"  modelReadinessState.xml`

I have no idea why it's not working :( I just get blanks returned back.

Note: **There are no namespaces defined in this xml file.**

Any ideas?

Comment: pluse-uno for beating the bushes to solve your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

```
xmlstarlet sel  -t -c  "//readiness"           modelReadinessState.xml

xmlstarlet sel  -t -c  "readiness/model/name"  modelReadinessState.xml

xmlstarlet sel  -t -v  "readiness/model/name"  modelReadinessState.xml
```